# 文字列から文字列への assoc を格納する変数を defcustom したい

Tags: elisp

ちょっとした文字列から文字列への assoc を、 elisp で処理したいことがあります。なので、この処理を定型化し、対応関係を customizable な変数として定義したいと思っています。

これを実現するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。もうちょっと具体的なやりたいこととしては、 customize-variable の画面から、この assoc を編集できるようになりたいと考えています。

defcustom は使ったことがないことと、マニュアルを見てもぱっとはどうしたらいいかわからないので、質問しています。

Comment: `package-archives`のようなものを自前で定義したい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: まさしくその通りなのですが、だとしたらこれを見ればよかったですね、、解決しました m(_ _)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package-archive を参考にすれば、たとえば次のようにすれば実現できました。

```
(defcustom my-assoc-list '(("aKey" . "aValue"))
  "Hogehoge"
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Some key")
                :value-type (string :tag "Some value")))
```